# vc++- strings and BSTR

Tags: visual-c++

```
  STDMETHODIMP Cencrypt::encry(BSTR* s, BSTR* a)
   {
    int len,i;
    len=int(strlen((char *)(s)));
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
    a[i]=s[i]+3;
   }
    a[i]='\0';
    return S_OK;
   }
```

This is the backend code that im using for simple string encryption... my front end is VB and it has the following code..

---

```
   Dim obj As New encrypt
   Dim s As String
   Dim a As String

   Private Sub Command1_Click()
   a = Text1.Text
   Call obj.encrypt(s, a)

   MsgBox (s)

    End Sub
```

But when i run my vb after referencing the dll, it does not execute... Can i know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

BSTRs are not regular C-strings, so you should stop thinking about them that way asap (for our own sanity).

They are specifically designed for COM usage, and as such have a bunch of special-purpose APIs for inspection and manipulation.  For starters check out [SysStringLen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (to get the length properly) and the wrapper class `_bstr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you show the IDL code where you define the interfaces for your encrypt object.

Another problem you have is assuming that the BSTRs are char*. They are not. They are double byte char arrays.